# Updatepanel for real time notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Is this gonna work for up to 1000 users? Having an update panel for specific HTML controls(MySQL database, select statements checking update in the database), just a small part that kept being refresh for 1 second or 500ms? Will it greatly affect the performance?
I am using web forms in asp.net

Comment: If you plan to refresh a section on certain interval you can use ajax, because it is more effective than using update panel. Below is the link which explains about improving update panel performance
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/140801/how-to-improve-asp-net-updatepanel-performance

Comment: Thanks po for the answer but I am only a student and I dont have much resources to test the website in the future for 1000 clients, with that quantity of clients is ajax compatible to handle those request without degradinh performance?

Comment: Both has some advantages and disadvantage, but for frequent updates in HTML it is better to use jquery ajax, because jQuery ajax is lighter weight and generally quicker, as an updatepanel forces a full postback cycle even if only a small amount of the resulting page is returned to the client.  So it is less efficient, but much easier to develop and your code still works with js disabled. 

Reference: https://forums.asp.net/t/2023279.aspx?Positive+characteristics+and+differences+between+jQuery+Ajax+and+the+UpdatePanel+in+aspx+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use an `UpdatePanel` if you are frequently refreshing the data and you got a server that does not support this many requests especially when you have thousands of users making requests, all hitting the same `database` and imagine if your `select` statements are not very well managed, and you have millions of records in your table that your select statement is filtering out each second for thousands of users. It could cause huge performance lags.

So, **Yes**, it will widely affect the performance.

Instead, move towards event driven approaches that only send you data when there is a change in the database, i.e when there is a notification in real time, such as `SignalR` and `SqlDependency`. This will be a lengthy thing to do but it will be a big plus in the performance of your application.

Otherwise, you can always move towards intelligent refreshing techniques such as hitting the server when the user is on page and the tab is focused. In that case, using `jQuery` `ajax` would be very beneficial.

So, to summarize it, you should not use UpdatePanel and refresh every second or every half second this will cause problems on a long run.

Comment: does signalr works with web forms in asp.net? Cause I already made the application in web forms version of asp.net

Comment: Yes it works fine with web forms, every platform has its own ways of consuming things. SignalR would not be much different for web forms as compared to other platforms